# Reading a JSON Array in android activity using recyclerview and cardview

Tags: java, android

I know how to Parse JSON object like below

```
  {
    "users": [{
            "id": 2,
            "username": "user",
            "full_name": "user full name",
            "profilePicture": "/images/profileimage.png"
        },

        {
            "id": 2,
            "username": "user2",
            "full_name": "user2 full name",
            "profilePicture": "/images/profileimage2.png"
        }
    ]
}
```

by calling JSON Object using recyclerview and cardview like this

```
  try {
                JSONObject response = new JSONObject(result);
                JSONArray users= response.optJSONArray("users");
                feedsList = new ArrayList<>();

                for (int i = 0; i < users.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject user = users.optJSONObject(i);
                    FeedItem item = new FeedItem();
                    item.setTitle(user.optString("full_name"));
                    item.setThumbnail(user.optString("profilePicture"));
                    feedsList.add(item);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

And i have the following JSON i want to read in android activity

```
[
     {
        "id": 2,
        "username": "user",
        "full_name": "user full name",
        "profilePicture": "/images/profileimage.png",
      },

      {
        "id": 2,
        "username": "user2",
        "full_name": "user2 full name",
        "profilePicture": "/images/profileimage2.png",
      }
    ]
```

Any one know how i can read this type of JSON  starting with [ instead of { can help me

Comment: What is the problem? You say you can parse the JSON but later you say you can't?

Comment: @Knight please check my answer.

Comment: your JSON is wrong check it on JSON LINT and check my answer @Denny

Comment: both of your JSON are malformed

Comment: Thanks what i want is to read the json started with [ and ending with ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to call the JSONArray first and parse the JSONObjects
like below

```
 try {

             JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

             feedsList = new ArrayList<>();

             for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                 JSONObject user = jArray.optJSONObject(i);
                 FeedItem item = new FeedItem();
                 item.setTitle(user.optString("full_name"));
                 item.setThumbnail(user.optString("profilePicture"));
                 feedsList.add(item);
             }
         } catch (JSONException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
```

Thanks for your ideas helps me so much!!

Answer (score 1):

**your mistake is you can use posts.length replace it users.lenth**

```
        try {

        JSONObject response = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONArray users= response.optJSONArray("users");
        feedsList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < users.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject user = users.optJSONObject(i);
            FeedItem item = new FeedItem();
            item.setTitle(user.optString("full_name"));
            item.setThumbnail(user.optString("profilePicture"));
            feedsList.add(item);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
      try {
                JSONObject response = new JSONObject(result);
                JSONArray users= response.getJSONArray("users");
                feedsList = new ArrayList<>();

                for (int i = 0; i < users.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject user = users.getJSONObject(i);
                    FeedItem item = new FeedItem();
                    item.setTitle(user.getString("full_name"));
                    item.setThumbnail(user.getString("profilePicture"));
                    feedsList.add(item);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is wrong

**Right JSON**

```
   {
    "users": [{
            "id": 2,
            "username": "user",
            "full_name": "user full name",
            "profilePicture": "/images/profileimage.png"
        },

        {
            "id": 2,
            "username": "user2",
            "full_name": "user2 full name",
            "profilePicture": "/images/profileimage2.png"
        }
    ]
}
```

and also replace your code with

```
try {
                JSONObject response = new JSONObject(result);
                JSONArray users= response.getJSONArray("users");
                feedsList = new ArrayList<>();

                for (int i = 0; i < users.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject user = users.getJSONObject(i);
                    FeedItem item = new FeedItem();
                    item.setTitle(user.getString("full_name"));
                    item.setThumbnail(user.getString("profilePicture"));
                    feedsList.add(item);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```